# Linking facebook sdk to ios

Tags: facebook, firebase, react-native

I have a dead line and dont know what to do with that. IM tryin to use react-native-fbsdk with firebase on and wanted to link the sdk to ios. Everything is good but this function:

```
[[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                           didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
  // Add any custom logic here.
  return YES;
```

Im trying to put this here:

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

  jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index.ios" fallbackResource:nil];

  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                      moduleName:@"tzawajna"
                                               initialProperties:nil
                                                   launchOptions:launchOptions];
  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;

  [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                           didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
  // Add any custom logic here.
  return YES;

}
```

And Its giving an error of

> use of undeclared identifier FBSDKApplicationDelegate

What should I do.

Thanks

Comment: did you import #import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h> ?

Answer (score 0):

Check whether In your application:openURL:options implementation ( or for any other method in the file), the parameter is named `app` and not `application`.

You can either change the parameter name in the method signature to application:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
            options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
```

This error can be caused because of the difference in the parameter of such method.

Comment: I didnt understand

Comment: In my code `(UIApplication *)application`, here application is a parameter. Sometimes this got changed to `app`.

Inspect every method in `AppDelegate.m` file if such things happened. It could be possible, that this happened in `openURL` method.

Comment: Everything is application